# Sum of values across all nested dictionaries in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary of Counters, e.g:

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

numbers = defaultdict(Counter)

numbers['a']['first'] = 1
numbers['a']['second'] = 2
numbers['b']['first'] = 3
```

I want to get the sum: 1+2+3 = 6

What would be the simplest / idiomatic way to do this in python 3?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a nested comprehension:

```
sum(x for counter in numbers.values() for x in counter.values())
```

Or sum first the counters (starting with an empty one), and then their values:

```
sum(sum(numbers.values(), Counter()).values())
```

Or first each counter's values, and then the intermediate results:

```
sum(sum(c.values()) for c in numbers.values())
```

Or use chain:

```
from itertools import chain
sum(chain.from_iterable(d.values() for d in numbers.values()))
```

I prefer the first way.

Answer (score 2):

```
sum(sum(c.values()) for c in numbers.values())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import chain
sum(chain.from_iterable(d.values() for d in numbers.values()))
# outputs: 6
```

In terms of performance use `.itervalues()` in python 2.x, that avoids building intermediary list (applies to all solutions here).

```
sum(chain.from_iterable(d.itervalues() for d in numbers.itervalues()))
```